# Ho do I set a property in ServletWebServerFactory bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, netflix-eureka

I have created a class in a library module that has a ServletWebServerFactory bean so that when my spring boot application starts this bean method is called so that I can set the port programmatically on the tomcat based on some environment properties.
Basically if server.port is not set then it uses SocketUtils to get a random available port within a range defined by server.port.min and server.port.max properties (or their defaults)

```
public class TomcatServlet {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TomcatServlet.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory() {

        String serverPort = environment.getProperty("server.port");

        // Note: min port number should be greater or equal to 49152 as lower values are either registered or semi-reserved
        int minPort = Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("server.port.min", "49152"));
        int maxPort = Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("server.port.max", "65535"));

        logger.info("server.port: {}, server.port.min: {}, server.port.max: {}", serverPort, minPort, maxPort);

        // if serverPort is defined then use that value
        int port;

        // if serverPort is not defined then get a random available port in the defined or default range
        if (serverPort == null) {
            // get an available port in the range
            port = getRandomPort(minPort, maxPort);
        } else {
            port = Integer.parseInt(serverPort);
        }
        logger.info("port to set tomcat on: {}", port);

        Long unloadDelay = Long.valueOf(environment.getProperty("tomcat.unload.timeout", "30000"));
        logger.info("Tomcat unloadDelay = {}", unloadDelay);

        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        Long finalUnloadDelay = unloadDelay;
        tomcat.addContextCustomizers(context -> {
            if(context instanceof StandardContext) {
                ((StandardContext) context).setUnloadDelay(finalUnloadDelay);
            }
        });
        tomcat.setPort(port);

        return tomcat;
    }

    private int getRandomPort(int minPort, int maxPort) {

        int returnPort = 0;
        try {
            returnPort = SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort(minPort, maxPort);
            logger.info("Random Server Port is {}.", returnPort);
        } catch( IllegalStateException e) {
            // no available port found so it will use the configured server.port value
            logger.warn("No port available in range {$minPort}-{$maxPort}. Default configuration {$returnPort} will be used.");
        }
        return returnPort;

    }
}
```

This all works fine, the tomcat starts up on the port expected and I can include this library into all of our services and they will all start on the expected ports.

**However**, each service is defined as a Eureka Client service and as such it registers itself with the Eureka Server. When it does this, it sends the server name and port number information to the Eureka Server.

The port number is taken from the server.port property which is not necessarily the port that the tomcat was started on. As such I would like to save the calculated port in the server.port property at the point it is calculated. Is there any way to access the applications properties such that they can be changed within my TomcatServlet class?

I did a test implementation of similar functionality in the main class of one of the services so that I could access SpringApplication and use the setDefaultProperties method to set the server.port in which case I would not have to do this in the library class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(AddressBSMain.class);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        int port = HttpUtils.getRandomPort(50000, 50100);
        properties.put("server.port", port);
        application.setDefaultProperties(properties);

        application.run(args);

    }
```

Again, this works fine. The only problem with this is that we would have to implement this change in every one of our 60 plus services. Ideally we would like to keep the code in our common library so that all we have to do is change each services maven pom file to change the dependency version

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have injected the SpringApplication in your TomcatServlet. Can't you set it on that?

Comment: Sorry that was my attempt to try and see it but the injection of SpringApplication failed at run time. I have now removed that line of code above

Comment: Have you tried to set it as a System Property? System.setProperty("server.port", yourport);?